# How to identify multiple entities in RASA

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I want to extract multiple entities from a user input.
Example- "Service httpd is not responding because of high CPU usage and DNS Error"
So here I want to identify below:
Httpd
High CPU usage
DNS Error

And I will be using this keywords to get a response from a Database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just annotate them accordingly, e.g.

```
## intent: query_error
- Service [httpd](keyword) is not responding because of [high CPU usage](keyword) and [DNS Error](keyword)
```

Having the sentence from above, Rasa NLU would extract 3 entities of type `keyword`. You can then access these entities in a [custom action](https://rasa.com/docs/core/customactions/#custom-actions-written-in-python) and query your database.

Regarding the number of examples which are required: this depends on

- the [NLU pipeline](https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/choosing_pipeline/) which you are using. Typically `tensorflow_embedding` requires more training examples than `spacy_sklearn` since it does not use pretrained language models.
- the number of different values your entities can have. If it is only `httpd`, `high CPU usage`, and `DNS error` then you don't need a lot of examples. However, if you have a thousand different values for your entity, then you need more training examples

One intent is enough if you always want to trigger the same custom action. However, if you want to classify different type of problems, e.g. server problems and client problems, and trigger different databases depending on the type of problems, you might consider having multiple intents.

Sorry for the vague answers, but in machine learning most things are highly dependent on the use case and the dataset.

Comment: how many such examples do I need to train to extract the entities correctly. also is it necessary that all training example should consists of three similar entities.

Comment: added it to my answer

Comment: How to fill the slot in stories.md with the list of keywords, so it can be used in a custom action?

Comment: @asmaier: autofilled by default from the intent (unless the slot has the parameter autofilled: false, or the slot has the type=unfeaturized)